# How to get Appium's inspector to refresh its UI on an Android Native App?

Tags: reactjs, appium, appium-android, inspector

Appium inspector is stuck with its loading animation in the UI section, not allowing to get the current UI and elements. How can it by bypassed?

I'm running Appium 1.13.0 on Windows, with a real Android device and trying to inspect a React native app. 
The inspector launches the app and shows the initial screen (environment chooser) and allows to inspect/select elements, but after tapping - it shows a loading animation which doesn't stop.
Attempting to refresh does nothing.
**On the device itself - the app has reached the desired screen.**

From Appium's logs, here's what happens after the tap:

```
[MJSONWP (6564ecbb)] Responding to client with driver.click() result: true

[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/6564ecbb-53f5-4c97-8456-f70f6ea3d747/element/1/click 200 141 ms - 76

[HTTP] 

[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":0,"value":true}

[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/6564ecbb-53f5-4c97-8456-f70f6ea3d747/source

[HTTP] {}

[MJSONWP (6564ecbb)] Calling AppiumDriver.getPageSource() with args: ["6564ecbb-53f5-4c97-8456-f70f6ea3d747"]

[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/6564ecbb-53f5-4c97-8456-f70f6ea3d747/screenshot

[HTTP] {}

[MJSONWP (6564ecbb)] Calling AppiumDriver.getScreenshot() with args: ["6564ecbb-53f5-4c97-8456-f70f6ea3d747"]

[AndroidBootstrap] Sending command to android: {"cmd":"action","action":"source","params":{}}

[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/6564ecbb-53f5-4c97-8456-f70f6ea3d747/window/current/size

[HTTP] {}

[MJSONWP (6564ecbb)] Calling AppiumDriver.getWindowSize() with args: ["current","6564ecbb-53f5-4c97-8456-f70f6ea3d747"]

[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"action","action":"source","params":{}}

[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type ACTION

[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command action: source
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

driver.FindElementByAndroidUIAutomator("UiSelector().text(\"WHATEVER TEXT\")").Click();

Thanks to @Dmitri T's reply, I've used Appium Studio to inspect the elements - which I couldn't inspect before due to the splash screen (I guess).
Later on, I was still unable to find elements by XPath and other methods, again - probably because of the splash screen.

What finally did the trick, was using FindElementByAndroidUIAutomator. Got a list of usages [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiSelector), and finally I'm able to find and click.

I understand that the solution is a bit different than my original question's title - but these 2 methods (Appium studio + FindElementByAndroidUIAutomator) provided the solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Appium Inspector has troubles getting the page source, try restarting the device/Appium Desktop and make sure nothing else is using the [adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) connection.

You can also consider using alternative tools which provide device UI inspection capabilities:

1. [Android Studio Layout Inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector)
2. [Android Device Monitor](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor)
3. [Appium Studio](https://experitest.com/mobile-test-automation/appium-studio/)

Comment: Thanks @dmitri-t, using Appium Studio I can again inspect elements!
Now I guess the problem is (and probably was...) the SplashScreen with the environment chooser. I can't switch to and from it... Any thoughts?

Comment: You can wait for spash screen presence/absence using [Explicit Waits](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits), check out [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/) article for more information on the concept with examples.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry T., I was finally able to find a solution with your inspectors suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Use can use refresh button in appium Desktop inspector to refresh the screen displyaed. You can see the refresh button in top side as shown in following figure.[image]

Comment: Thanks Suban, that's the first thing I've tries... I can see the refresh command in the log, but the loading animation doesn't change